# Having issues trying to understand how callback queries work in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'd like to make a telegram bot that when started sends a hello world message with an inline button that when clicked sends another hello world messge, but the code (the one below) that I'm using doesn't work. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Using `python-telegram-bot==20.0a0`

```
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

from TOKEN import TOKEN


keyboard = [
    [InlineKeyboardButton("Start", callback_data="start")],
]

start_query_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)


async def start(update, context) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text("Hello World!", reply_markup=start_query_keyboard)

def start2(callback) -> None:
    callback.message.reply_text("Hello World!")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()

    app.add_handlers([CommandHandler("start", start), CallbackQueryHandler("start", start2)])

    app.run_polling(stop_signals=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `CallbackQueryHandler` must be a callback function, not a string. That callback function must accept exactly two positional arguments  and must be a coroutine function (`async def`), just as for `CommandHandler` (or any other handler, in fact). Please have a look at the [docs of `CallbackQueryhandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a2/telegram.ext.callbackqueryhandler.html) as well as the [`inlinekeyboard.py` example](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a2/examples.html#examples-inlinekeyboard) .

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I can't really understand what you mean, could you please correct the code that I put in the question so I can understand it better? If you don't have time or you don't want to do it it's ok, I'll try to find a way to make it work

Comment: Nevermind resolved it, I took the example given by you and modified it according to my needs. Thanks.